# CS50 Problem Set 2: Readability Code Math Not Working

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_letters(string text);
int count_words(string text);
int count_sentences(string text);

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    int number = count_letters(text);
    int number_of_words = count_words(text);
    int sentences = count_sentences(text);

    int L = (number / number_of_words) * 100;
    int S = (sentences/number_of_words) * 100;
    int index = (0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8;

    if (index < 16 && index > 1)
    {
        printf("Text: %s\n %i letters\n %i words\n %i sentences\n", text, number, number_of_words, sentences);
        printf("L:%i\n", L);
        printf("S:%i\n", S);
        printf("Grade:%i\n", index);
        printf("Grade %i\n", (int) round(index));
    }
    else if (index < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade: 16+\n");
    }

}

//sentence counter
int sentences = 0;

int count_sentences(string text)
{
    int lengths = strlen(text);

    for (int i = 0; i < lengths; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '?' || text [i] == '!')
        {
            sentences = sentences + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            sentences = sentences + 0;
        }
    }
    return sentences;
}


//word counter
int words = 1;

int count_words(string text)
{
    int length = strlen(text);

    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        if(isspace(text[j]))
        {
            words = words + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            words = words + 0;
        }
    }
    return words;
}

//letter counter
int letters = 0;

int count_letters(string text)
{
    int len = strlen(text);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            letters = letters + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            letters = letters + 0;
        }
    }
    return letters;
}
```

I used the debugging tool and I know that the problem is with the calculations, but the thing is I don't understand why, all the math should be correct and I'm also getting the correct number of letters, words, and sentences. I added all the printf's to be able to see the numbers myself in the terminal. Whenever I try the sentence, "There are more things in Heaven and Earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy." I get grade 7 instead of 9.

Comment: It seems odd that `letters` is a global variable, rather than scoped to `count_letters`. This does mean that between calls to `count_letters` it's never reset to `0`. Same with `words` and `sentences`.

Comment: Have you considered that `number / number_of_words` is an integer division? Also, `round(index)` doesn't make much sense, given that `index` is an `int` too.